# Objective C - change arrangement of UIImageview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uiimageview, xib

I have created a `UIImageView` in my code:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 60, 180, 180)];
[self.view addSubview:background];
```

and I have also got a `UIImageView` in my XIB. The programmatically-created `UIImageView` appears on top of the XIB's `UIImageView`. How do I change this so the XIB's `UIImageView` appears on top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would put my background directly in the nib file. But to add it programmatically, use `insertSubview:belowSubview:`, `insertSubview:atIndex:`, or `sendSubviewToBack:` to put it where you want it.